# Android studio compile error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, gradle, android-studio

This is an error that Android Studio spat out at me, I have no idea what it means. Does anyone have any insight into this?

```
Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5 sec
Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Error:Gradle: A problem
occurred configuring project ':repulse'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':repulse:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+.
        Required by:
            repulseProject:repulse:unspecified
```

Comment: You probably need to install the support library - see the last paragraph at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Check in your SDK Manager if you have support repository. Check if you have to use  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' instead of  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0', and if error persists, post your build.gradle

Comment: Tried it, it still didn't work. http://pastebin.com/YBX9ErE8